# Disable history in etcd key value store

Tags: go, etcd, etcd3, etcdctl

Is there any way to disable the history saving in etcd?

I am going to use etcd as KV for my app and I don't need history for the key values.

When I search etcd, I couldn't find about disabling the history.

I don't want to use the compacting feature in etcd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event history is part of etcd.

It was acknowledged, as far back as 2015 in [issue 4432](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4432) ("Consider moving events out of etcd") that:

> Events account for the overwhelming majority of our etcd write volume, which is causing a variety of performance and stability problems.
> We could consider a different delivery mechanism for the events.

But for now, this is still managed by etcd.

There are other Key-Value referential which might prove simpler to manage than etcd in your case. I use [`prologic/bitcask`](https://git.mills.io/prologic/bitcask).

Comment: thanks vonc. seems bitcask is best fit for few million keys where in my case it might exceed. Decided to use etcd with auto periodic compact

Comment: @Vijayakumar Just out of curiosity, would multiple bitcask databases, with data sharding, be a simpler solution than etcd?

Comment: In etcd also we are going to use multiple cluster like tenant , core. In some clusters (tenant) where we store data which would be queried on each request, will exceed millions in  keys. We are looking for distributed KV where bitraft lack of documentation and we don't want use redis based protocol. etcd seems simpler to us and for distributed it has more features like add, remove member which we would use in future.

Comment: @Vijayakumar OK, makes sense. Thank you for the feedback.